# ListView exception

Tags: android, listview

I am working on a project where I load some data from a remote database and display them in `ListView`. The data are loaded properly but the problem is displaying them in `Listview` (`SimpleAdapter`). The class extends `ListActivity`.

Code:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){

        progressDialog.dismiss();

        try{
            if(jsonObject.getInt("success") == 1){
                jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("notes");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject o = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Note tempNote = new Note(o.getInt("note_id"), o.getString("description"), o.getString("data"));
                    userData.addNote(tempNote);

                    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hashMap.put("id", o.getString("note_id"));
                    hashMap.put("description", o.getString("description"));
                    userNotes.add(hashMap);
                    Log.d(TAG, userNotes.get(0).toString());

                }

            }
            Toast.makeText(UserNotes.this, jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ListAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(UserNotes.this, 
                        userNotes, 
                        R.layout.list_note, 
                        new String[] {"id, description"},
                        new int[] {R.id.list_note_id, R.id.list_note_description});
                setListAdapter(listAdapter);
            }

        });
        }
```

Error:

```
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.bindView(SimpleAdapter.java:160)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:126)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getView(SimpleAdapter.java:114)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1198)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1109)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-02 08:05:09.964: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

list_note.xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_note_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_note_description"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

user_notes.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I would appreciate if somebody could give me a solution to fix this exception.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please list your layout of list_note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what u have done in your code is

```
ListAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(UserNotes.this, 
                        userNotes, 
                        R.layout.list_note, 
                        new String[] {"id, description"},
                        new int[] {R.id.list_note_id, R.id.list_note_description});
```

change this to

```
ListAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(UserNotes.this, 
                        userNotes, 
                        R.layout.list_note, 
                        new String[] {"id", "description"},
                        new int[] {R.id.list_note_id, R.id.list_note_description});
```

you have done `new String[] {"id, description"}` which should be
 `new String[] {"id", "description"}`

Comment: Haha, how is that possible that I did not see that?:) Thanks a lot man!!! You saved me several hours probably! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just Change ListAdapter to Simple Adapter and add hashmap object into hashmap arraylist out of for loop.

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){

         progressDialog.dismiss();

    try{
        if(jsonObject.getInt("success") == 1){
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("notes");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject o = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                Note tempNote = new Note(o.getInt("note_id"), o.getString("description"), o.getString("data"));
                userData.addNote(tempNote);

                HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hashMap.put("id", o.getString("note_id"));
                hashMap.put("description", o.getString("description"));

                Log.d(TAG, userNotes.get(0).toString());

            }
                userNotes.add(hashMap);

        }
        Toast.makeText(UserNotes.this, jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            SimpleAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(UserNotes.this, 
                    userNotes, 
                    R.layout.list_note, 
                    new String[] {"id, description"},
                    new int[] {R.id.list_note_id, R.id.list_note_description});
            setListAdapter(listAdapter);
        }

    });
    }
```

Comment: Id say that changing ListAdapter to SimpleAdapter will not make any difference. Its just Interface and concrete implementation of that interface. Btw that hashMap should be added to that ArrayList in for loop. Anyway, I will try your solution :)

Comment: I added both xml files, check it please :)

Comment: In your list_note.xml file have you used Relativelayout or LinearLayout??

Comment: I think you have missed this lines ListView lv = getListView();........Therefore you can't get data in listview...So just try it.

Comment: I got it somewhere else, it is all right, the problem has already been solved but thanks! :)